# update textbox control value on client side Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Is it possible to fill value for a text box control value on selection of value from dropdown control on out of box NewForm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add the JQuery below to NewForm.aspx. This code sets a field named `My Text Field` to the value of a field named `My Dropdown Field` when the dropdown is changed.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[title='My Dropdown Field']").change(function(){
        $("input[title='My Text Field']").val($("select[title='My Dropdown Field'] option:selected").text());
    });
});
</script>
```